# A problem occurred configuring project ':app'. > compileSdkVersion is not specified

Tags: java, android, react-native, gradle

For my React native project when I run `npx react-native run-android` I get this error:

> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
> Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
> See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
>
> FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
>
> ### 1: Task failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Build file 'HIDING_MY_PATH_ON_PURPOSE/mobileappname/android/app/build.gradle'
>   line: 126
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
>
> > HIDING_MY_PATH_ON_PURPOSE/mobileappname/android/app/release.properties
> > (No such file or directory)
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
>   ==============================================================================
>
> ### 2: Task failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
>
> > compileSdkVersion is not specified.
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
>   ==============================================================================
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 1s
>
> error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android
> development environment set up:
> https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose
> flag for more details. Error: Command failed: ./gradlew
> app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

As there are two errors so for the first one I went to `app/build.gradle` and this is line `126`

[image]

I've never changed anything in this file, this is how as default it has been created from start.

The `java --version` I'm using is:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_242-release"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.242-b3-6915495, mixed mode)
```

And in my `~/.bash_profile` I've added these at the end:

[image]

Finally in my android studio's SDK Platform I've `Android 10.0 (Q)` selected and have all of these SDK Tools installed:

[image]

I've followed many things from the answers but still haven't been able to run the app on an Android emulator.

Comment: @ Chaudhry Talha , have you abe tp resolve this issue ?

Comment: @sunilkalwani it's been some time so I don't remember what I did or why this error was occuring but check (just to be on the safe side) the version of `compileSdkVersion` in `android/build.gradle`. It should match the one that is installed on your computer.